# Newbie PHP. Why is this an undefined index?

Tags: php, drupal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

I've skimmed through docs and this site but still unsure.  I'm working with Drupal 7.

Printing the variable with this code:

```
<?php print $info['comments'] ?>
```

If there are zero comments I get

```
Notice: Undefined index as a message.
```

If it exists, it prints the correct #.

Any help would be appreciated. How do I set it so if there are no comments it displays a zero?

Thanks!

Comment: An undefined index is just an undefined index. There is not more to it than that. You have to give us some context or show us an example of what you trying to do, if you want help with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To print an integer no matter what:

```
 <?php print @intval($info['comments']) ?>
```

Or to irrevocably suppress the notice:

```
 <?php print isset($info['comments']) ? $info['comments'] : 0 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know drupal, and don't know your context exactly, but if you try to access an index that doesn't exists from an array, this kind of notice is displayed.

To avoid such a thing, you can do something like :

```
if(isset($info['comments'])) {
    print $info['comments'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP arrays are associative by nature, thus you can have an array composed of all types of keys/values:

```
arry['stringkey'] = 'somestring';
arry[1] = 'some other string';
etc..
```

If you were to try and reference an index in the array that is not present without doing any error checking, like so

```
if(arry[2] == 'some third string')
```

you'd get an 'undefined index' error. Look into the `isset()` function for a solution.

Comment: your example would still give an "undefined index" error. you must check isset before checking equality.

Comment: @hackattack please reread my answer.

Comment: Unclear to me if your example is what you think is a proper error check or an example of what will throw an error. I see now its the former, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You could test if the array has that key:

```
if (array_key_exists('comments', $info)) {
...
}
```

But I am not sure if that is what you really want to do.